# Python, using Full .NET?

Tags: .net, python, dynamic-language-runtime

I was trying out [python in my browser using silverlight](http://ironpython.net/try/) which is cool. Can i use python with .NET in a console or winform app? I hear silverlight is a stripped down .NET so it will load (or have a smaller download) on client machines. Can i use python with the full power of .NET? (perhaps outside of silver light)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, check out IronPython: http://ironpython.codeplex.com/

It will work in any .NET app.

Answer (score 3):

You might try looking at [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).

Additionally, there's the [Python for .NET](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/) project, but I haven't read much on it.

Comment: IronPython = the official .NET implementation of Python. Python for .NET = something I've never heard of before and almost certainly inferior to IronPython.

Comment: I've not heard much on it either and IronPython would probably be a more complete solution, but in the interest of being thorough I added it on there for anyone who might find this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/), maybe? It's a CLR implementation of Python. Totally .NET and totally cool.

From their site:

> IronPython is an implementation of the
>   Python programming language running
>   under .NET and Silverlight. It
>   supports an interactive console with
>   fully dynamic compilation. It's well
>   integrated with the rest of the .NET
>   Framework and makes all .NET libraries
>   easily available to Python
>   programmers, while maintaining
>   compatibility with the Python
>   language. There also is Visual Studio
>   tooling integration.